# how to float the section tags in html5

Tags: html, css

this might be a wee easy question, and so, how to float - left the `<section>` tag? i tried to use `float: left;` but does not work or is it possible to align vertically the  tag along with content of it?

here's my try.

html.

```
<div id="divcontent">
    <section>
        <h1>heyo</h1>
        <a href="dropitinmyass.html" ><p>asdasdasdasd</p></a>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>heyo</h1>
        <a href="dropitinmyass.html" ><p>asdasdasdasd</p></a>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>heyo</h1>
        <a href="dropitinmyass.html" ><p>asdasdasdasd</p></a>
    </section>
</div>
```

and here's the css.

```
#divcontent {overflow: auto; padding: 15px;}
#divcontent section {float:left; width: 300px;}
```

Answer (score 3):

All `HTML5` new elements are `inline` by default. You have to specify `display:block` for all of them, which are supposed to be displayed as `div`s.

```
#divcontent {overflow: auto; padding: 15px;}
#divcontent section {display: block; float: left; width: 300px;}
```

Comment: `All HTML5 new elements are inline by default` Where did you get that information from?

Comment: @Musa Particularly my browsers display **Juliver Galleto's** code correctly. But browsers treat unknown elements as `inline`. So I assumed that author has an old browser and need to specify `display` property.

Comment: only old browsers, ie6 ie7 ie8 see section as inline element, all others see it as a block-level element

Answer (score 0):

You can just `float` `<section>` like it was a `<div>`
Best you give it a `width` too, so that floats are working.

```
section {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  display: block; /* for old browsers */
}
```