# Floating element issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with my `h1` and `floating` element

I want `page number` h1 element to be aligned on the right side of my `presentation` text.

Chrome display the results well but not firefox..the `page number` texts are within one of my slide images.

Here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/A3RXg/3/

Can someone help me out?

Thansk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/89dQr/.

Updated CSS code

```
#page-count{
  float: right;
}

.break {
  clear: both;
}

h1{
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

`white-space: nowrap;`

from CSS for

`#slide-container`

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A3RXg/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a "section" tag you need to specify a width. Otherwise I would recommend using a DIV tag. I believe your iissue is that a section tag doesn't have a width and doesn't resize based on contents.

See "[how to float the section tags in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916334/how-to-float-the-section-tags-in-html5)" for information on float + section tags.

Answer (score 0):

you simply can wrap your h1

```
<div style="float:left; width:300px;">
    <h1>Presentation</h1>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
    <h1 >page number</h1>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox refuses to show floated elements inline with non-floated elements that exist under the same parent element. (Firefox always uses `display:block;` for floated elements.)

Either use `position:relative;` on the parent element and use absolute positioning for the `h1`s, or float both "Presentation" and "page number".